# Is it possible to suppress fields from API results?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

For example, I wish to get the like count for each post without getting name and Id details of each like.

The `likes` attribute returned for a call to `me/posts?fields=likes.summary(true)` would be:

```
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "aaa",
            "name": "bbb"
          },
          {
            "id": "ccc",
            "name": "ddd"
          },
          ...
          ...
        ],
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 56,
          "can_like": true,
          "has_liked": false
        }
      }
```

It's the "data" attribute I'd like to suppress coming back due to it (and the same for `comments` and other fields I'd like to turn off) substantially increasing the bandwidth of data received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's the "data" attribute I'd like to suppress coming back due to it (and the same for comments and other fields I'd like to turn off) substantially increasing the bandwidth of data received.

Specify a limit of 0, then you will just get an empty data structure:

```
me/posts?fields=likes.summary(true).limit(0)
```

Comment: So it does! I'll remember that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you enumerate the post id's, you can then get the summary of likes for each post by calling:

```
/<post-id>/likes?summary=true&fields=total_count
```

This returns something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "<id>"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "...",
      "after": "..."
    }
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 3,
    "can_like": true,
    "has_liked": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I did actually wish to see the like count for each post rather than that for an entire page. I edited the post to make that clearer.

Comment: Well... that's exactly what my answer does. For a given post ID, it returns total like count. With none of the details of individuals who 'liked' the post. Just the `total_count`. Oh - looks like I had a typo in the API call - should have been post-id - fixed now.

Comment: Ah, yes I thought you meant what you found was a typo, and were getting the total likes for a page.

`/{post-id}/...` does indeed return less data than seeing every liker's name an id, but unfortunately I'll likely hit API call limits interrogating each post like this for a typical timeline.